# How do conditional operators in Python work for sets and tuples?

Tags: python, set, tuples, comparison-operators

I have written these lines in python:

```
print({1, 2, 3} < {1, 3, 2})
```

```
print((1, 2, 3) < (1, 3, 2))
```

These gives output:

```
False
```

```
True
```

I could not understand the working of `<` operator for two sets and two tuples. Please explain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you think the answer should be instead? Why? Did you try to find and read documentation about it? For example, you can try to put [`python set less than`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+set+less+than) or [`python tuple less than`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+tuple+less+than) into a search engine.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that you are supposed to ask one question at a time.